# CSS background-image url() not showing with error '404 not found' in various browsers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image

I'm building a bootstrap-4 project in Atom editor and my problem is that my CSS background-image url() is not showing...
I can see the file present in my developer console but with the error-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

Before all of you guys mark my question as a duplicate etc. please give me a chance to say that i have gone through almost all of the existing questions regarding this issue but everything i have tried so far has not worked and its really frustrating.

I have tried every single file path adjustment with no result.  If this is something simple then i hope the code gods of stackoverflow have some mercy upon this question i am almost intermediate level so i will appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

my file structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmuOR.jpg

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  color: #505962;
}



.navbar {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)!important;
}

#gint {
  word-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #1ebba3;
}

/*--start landing page--*/
.home-inner {
  background-image: url(images\landing.jpeg);
}
```

Comment: try it background-image: url(images/landing.jpeg);

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this in the very beginning but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the file path is correct, I see two problems for you:

1. You should use a forwards slash, not a backwards slash – i.e., `images/landing.jpeg`, **not** `images\landing.jpeg`
2. You need quotes around the file path, inside the parentheses: `background-image: url('images/landing.jpeg')`

Comment: I appreciate your input a lot.However i want to mention that i have already tried with the / slash. But with no result. unfortunately.

Comment: @El-Santo make sure you also use the quotes around the image path. Leaving those out is guaranteed to cause a problem for you.

Comment: I have also tried with the parentheses but still no results. Its really weird nothing seems to work. I have a logo which i added to my nav via the html which worked perfectly fine but this one is not working in CSS.

Comment: @El-Santo not just parentheses, **quotes** around the image path. In your code you have `url(some-path)`, but you need `url('some-path')`. The correct syntax for `background-image` is `url('…')`, where you fill in the ellipsis with your file path.

Comment: Yes you mean like this right, screenshot from my editor: https://imgur.com/a/mbQbeMF  ?

Comment: @El-Santo that is correct. If you still get a 404 with that syntax, then the file path is wrong. The error in your browser console should tell you the file path you are trying to load, so you can see what the problem is and adjust accordingly. (For example, if it says cannot load `bs4images/landing.jpeg`, then you can see you need to add a slash before `images`.)

Comment: Thanks, i will try this now and let you know.

Comment: the funny thing now is that the browser console is not showing the original error 404- but the image still doesn't show.

Comment: @El-Santo In that case it seems the problem you asked about is solved, but if you are still having trouble getting the image to show, you can post another question once you've tried to debug it yourself a bit. One thing to remember is that your image can't show up if the element it's the background of doesn't have a width and/or height. If you are satisfied with this solution to the 404 problem, you can accept this answer.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for the help. You did indeed solve my problem because just now as i suspected earlier i realized that my problem was not with the image-url but with certain width/height utilities that i was completely not aware of until i went back and had a proper look. Thanks again, appreciate it :)

Answer (score -1):

Just disable Chrome "Dark Reader" extension.